# I am having the following trouble with Crainiate. What could be the issue?

Tags: c#, .net

[image: Component Description]

I get the above window when I launch an application. The OK button enables after 5 seconds. On clicking OK it's supposed to open the application. It opens only when I run as administrator. Otherwise nothing happens.

The application is written in C# and .NET. Can anyone please help me with this?